# Changing fragments in tabs in tablayout during runtime

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I wonder if somebody could help me. I need to change fragment within individual tabs during runtime. I know it should be done using FragmentPagerAdapter, but that's all I have managed to find out about it. I'm using android studio. My project is running on API 22. Thanks for all answers!
Edit: Here's the code.

Here I set the tabbed layout class

```
Stack<Fragment> Tab1;
Stack<Fragment> Tab2;
Stack<Fragment> Tab3;

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_root);

    /*Tab1 = new Stack<Fragment>();
    Tab1.addElement(new Tab1Informations());
    Tab2 = new Stack<Fragment>();
    Tab2.addElement(new Tab2Events());
    Tab3 = new Stack<Fragment>();
    Tab3.addElement(new tab3tests());*/

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    //mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Tab1.peek(), Tab2.peek(), Tab3.peek());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),new Tab1Informations(), new Tab2Events(), new tab3tests());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    CreateButtonListener();
}
```

Here I tried to change the SectionChangedAdapter

```
Stack<Fragment> Tab1;
Stack<Fragment> Tab2;
Stack<Fragment> Tab3;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_root);

    /*Tab1 = new Stack<Fragment>();
    Tab1.addElement(new Tab1Informations());
    Tab2 = new Stack<Fragment>();
    Tab2.addElement(new Tab2Events());
    Tab3 = new Stack<Fragment>();
    Tab3.addElement(new tab3tests());*/
    //mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
     SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Tab1.peek(), 
     Tab2.peek(), Tab3.peek());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
   SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),new Tab1Informations(), 
    new Tab2Events(), new tab3tests());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
    TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
    TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    CreateButtonListener();
}
```

And here I defined the adapter itself.
                   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends 
                   FragmentPagerAdapter{
                   Fragment tab1;
                   Fragment tab2;
                   Fragment tab3;

```
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment tab1, Fragment 
    tab2, Fragment tab3){
        super(fm);
        this.tab1 = tab1;
        this.tab2 = tab2;
        this.tab3 = tab3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.InformationsTabTitle);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.EventsTabTitle);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.TestsTabTitle);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Your question is currently missing research for your problem. Your problem is nothing that hasn't come up before so by simply googling your problem or using the search function here you should easily find a tutorial helping you to solve your problem. If you narrow down the scope of your question to a specific problem though and include some code of you trying to solve this problem, we are surely able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` has `notifyDataSetChanged` method same as a listview adapter, and works similar to it. Your adapter returns fragment by the index, and you have to change what it returns, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 0):

if not using view pager

```
    //..............

tabLayoutMain = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMain);
tabLayoutMain.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    selectTab(tab);
  }

  private void selectTab(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    // do something
    tabText = "" + tab.getText();
    handelTabsSelection(tabText);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
      selectTab(tab);

      tabLayoutMain.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
          selectTab(tab);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab arg0) {
        }
      });

    }
  }


  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
  }

});
```

and

```
private void handelTabsSelection(String tabText) {
switch (tabText) {
  case "news":
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, new NewsFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    break;
  default:
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();



}

}
```